# Access content of artifact inside Artifactory execution user plugin

Tags: plugins, artifactory

Is it possible to access the content of an artifact inside an [Artifactory execution user plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-Executions)?

I'd like to unzip a file an read a nested JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `afterCreate` method of UserPlugins-Storage https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-Storage

For example take a look at https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/storage/remoteBackup